# How to upgrade to 8.1.0 using composer?

Tags: 8, composer

I used `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project` and have happily been using `composer install` `composer require` and `composer update` to keep my development system up-to-date and moving it around different development machines.

However, the upgrade to Drupal 8.1.0 from 8.0.6 was clumsier that I'd expected. Is there a slicker way of upgrading all the `symfony` dependencies than this?

```
composer require drupal/entity:8.1.0-alpha2 drupal/core:8.1.0 \
    symfony/process:~2.8 symfony/console:~2.8 symfony/event-dispatcher:~2.8 \
    symfony/yaml:~2.8 symfony/translation:~2.8 symfony/validator:~2.8 \
    symfony/serializer:~2.8 symfony/routing:~2.8  symfony/http-foundation:~2.8 \
    symfony/http-kernel:~2.8 symfony/dependency-injection:~2.8 \
    symfony/class-loader:~2.8

drush @mysdevsite updb

drush @mydevsite cr
```

**BTW**
This current (25 April) sole answer to the duplicate question didn't work for me. e.g. `- drupal/entity 8.0.1 requires drupal/system <8.1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.0.6, 8.0.x-dev].` caused `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.` So I had to require each of 8.1.0's dependencies in turn just the same as without the `--update-with-dependencies` option. Painful.

Comment: I think so too. Since there was no response and the question is very similar, I voted to close as duplicate. There's little benefit to repeat the answer here.  And in this case, drupal-project is used, so my suggestion there should work fine.

Comment: Yes the referenced question looks to be similar. Just haven't had a chance to try the solution.

Comment: I can confirm that the answer to the duplicate question doesn't work for me.

Comment: The answer to the duplicate question does work for me now. Apologies for dissing the answer. Can't explain what's changed to make it work as advised.